# js как сделать увеличение отступа при движении мышью?

Tags: javascript, html, css, разработка-игр

Я пока новичок в js.

Хочу сделать примитивную игру **заяц и черепаха**.

Вверху картинка с зайцем, а ниже с черепахой. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при движении мыши на картинке черепахи,она начинала двигаться вправо (увеличивать отступ слева и т.п.), а когда она начнёт двигаться, заяц тоже должен начать своё движение. И когда кто-нибудь дойдёт до финиша, должно появится диалоговое окно с победителем. Вроде всё понятно, но не получается с помощью onmousemove и `i++` сдвигать влево `marginLeft`.  Сдвигается только один раз.

```js
var rabbit = document.getElementById('rabbit');
var turtle = document.getElementById('turtle');

turtle.onmousemove = function() {
  var i = 0;
  i++;
  turtle.style.marginLeft = 0 + i + 'px';
}
```

```css
#rabbit {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background-image: url(images/009_017_rabbit_animal_nature_speed_fast_quick-128.png)
}

#turtle {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background: url(images/Turtle-2-128.png) no-repeat;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rabbit"></div>

<div id="turtle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var rabbit = document.getElementById('rabbit');
var turtle = document.getElementById('turtle');
var speedRabbit = 0;
var speedTurtle = 0;

turtle.onmousemove = function() {
  speedTurtle++;
  turtle.style.marginLeft = speedTurtle + 'px';
 
 if (!speedRabbit) {
   motionRabbit();
 }
}

function motionRabbit() {
 speedRabbit++;
  rabbit.style.marginLeft = speedRabbit + 'px';
  
  setTimeout(motionRabbit, 50); // Скорость движения блока зайца(В данном случае 1px/50миллисекунд)
}
```

```css
#rabbit {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#turtle {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rabbit">Заяц</div>
<div id="turtle">Черепаха</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var rabbit = document.getElementById('rabbit');
var turtle = document.getElementById('turtle');
var i = 0;

turtle.onmousemove = function (){   
    i++;
    turtle.style.marginLeft =0+i+'px';
}
```

```css
#rabbit{
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background: grey;
    }
#turtle{
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background: green;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rabbit"></div>

<div id="turtle"></div>
```

Анонимная функция вызывается каждый раз когда указатель мыши двигается над элементом turtle, и по вашему коду оно  каждый раз сначала устанавливает значение i в 0.
Достаточно просто обявить i вне функции и все заработает